# How to send multiple inputs to the remote shell using subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run multiple commands on a remote computer after doing ssh to that machine and then running commands on its terminal.

I want to use subprocess for this work. So I wrote the following command:-

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', 'rahul@172.20.70.121'], shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Now I get the terminal of remote machine and I pass the following command which gets executed on that machine:-

```
print process.communicate('python test.py /home/rahul/vPath-dissector')
```

But when I am again calling the last called command, it gives an error:-

```
print process.communicate('python temp.py /home/rahul/vPath-dissector')
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 690, in communicate
   self.stdin.write(input)
   ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

So what command can I use to send multiple commands without closing the file???

Comment: Did you try `process.stdin.write('python temp.py /home/rahul/vPath-dissector')` instead of using `communicate`?

Comment: Hi, then how will I get the output of the above command?? I am unable to get its output....

Comment: `process.stdout.readlines()`?

Comment: No, there is some issue with this... let me check... I need to specify stdout in the subprocess.Popen command..... otherwise, it will not recognize stdout and when I did that, its not showing the output. There might be some issue with that...

Answer (score 2):

Trying to find the answer to the same problem I ended up using [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html) instead of subprocess.

```
import pexpect

ssh = pexpect.spawn('ssh rahul@172.20.70.121')

prompts = [">", "#", "\$", "}", '%', pexpect.TIMEOUT]
ssh.sendline('echo Hello')
ssh.expect(prompts)
print ssh.before
```

For ssh specific there is even [pxssh](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pxssh.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is useful for you since you asked explicitely for subprocess.Popen 
- still, you can simply execute your remote command from the shell using

```
ssh rahul@172.20.70.121 python test.py /home/rahul/vPath-dissector
```

and of course from python with

```
os.system("ssh rahul@172.20.70.121 python test.py /home/rahul/vPath-dissector")
```

You can also capture the output of this command.

Sorry if I missed your point, though...

Comment: His question was about sending multiple commands to a single ssh process.

Comment: sure, but maybe Rahul can accomplish his goal with multiple ssh-connections as well - or do you see any problem with using separate ssh-calls?

Comment: Hi, I want to explicitly use subprocess here.... os.system is not the efficient way of doing the system calls as even written on the python's website. Even they suggest of using subprocess rather than os.system .

Answer (score 0):

When I had a similar problem years ago I ended up using this [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/440554-module-to-allow-asynchronous-subprocess-use-on-win/) from the Python Cookbook. Apparently it is now also available from [Pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/async_subprocess/), but I don't know if it's exactly the same code or not.

Comment: Doesn't look like the same code to me. The pip module doesn't work at all (it always returns `(None, None)` despite my having passed `PIPE` in to `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`.) Going to see if the other module works better.

Comment: No, you're right. I thought I had added a comment to point it out, but if I did it was't here.

Comment: Is that recipe your best suggestion still, 3 years later? I'm probably going to give it a shot first thing tomorrow (I read your post just before heading home for the day and just quickly tried the module on pip and found that it didn't work.) I'd go with `pexpect` except it seems to be Unix only, and I'd like a cross platform solution.